# Fill an existing numpy array with a scalar function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1 dimensional `numpy` array that needs to be refilled with data. The data at a given index is computed by a function `foo`

What I currently have is something like

```
for in in range(n):
    arr[i] = foo(i, state)
```

This is the performance bottleneck of the code. I considered `numpy.fromiter` but it returns a new array everytime. I would rather reuse the array to save space and time.

Comment: From my experience, populating a Python array and then converting it to a `numpy` array works much better

Comment: Without seeing `foo` this is impossible to answer.  If `foo` isn't a function of `arr[:i]` you should be able to vectorize it and do `arr = foo(state)`

Comment: If `fromiter` is faster than your loop, then it is saving both space and time.  Python/numpy recycles memory; you usually shouldn't worry about that detail.

Comment: @DanielForsman I don't have control over `Foo` it something we import from a C module. Had np.fromiter been able to use an existing numpy array and not return a new one that would have been perfect. The array len is big about 10^7 to 10^8 so cant afford to keep/create copies.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes fromiter comes out faster for certain sizes of n. But n is big for our case (10^7 ~ 10^8) and we cant afford to generate such big temporaries.